# PHP looping over query to perform conditional inserts or updates

Tags: php, sql

I have a php script that I've been running that seems to have been working but now I'm wondering if some of my logic is potentially off.

I select records from a db table within a date range which I put into an array called `$validCount`

If that array is not empty, that means I have valid records to update with my values, and if it's empty I just insert. The trick with the insert is that if the `STORES`  is less than the `Quantity` then it only inserts as many as the `STORES` otherwise it inserts as many as `Quantity`.

So if a record being inserted with had

```
Stores: 14 Quantity:12
```

Then it would only insert 12 records but if it had

```
Stores:1  Quantity:20
```

It would only insert 1 record.

In short, for each customer I should only ever have as many valid records (within a valid date range) as they have stores. If they have 20 stores, I can have 1 or 2 records but should never have 30.

It seems like updating works fine but I'm not sure if it's updating the proper records, though it seems like in some instances it's just inserting too many and not accounting for past updated records.

Does anything seem outright incorrect with the logic here?

```
if(!empty($validCount)){
        for($i=0; $i<$row2['QUANTITY']; $i++){
            try{
                $updateRslt = $update->execute($updateParams);
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                $out[] = $failedUpdate;
            }
        }
}else{  
    if($row2["QUANTITY"] >= $row2["STORES"]){
        for($i=0; $i<$row2["STORES"]; $i++){     
            try{
                $insertRslt = $insert->execute($insertParams);
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                $out[] = $failedInsertStore;
            }
        }
    }elseif($row2["QUANTITY"] < $row2["STORES"]){
        for($i=0; $i<$row2["QUANTITY"]; $i++){   
            try{
                $insertRslt = $insert->execute($insertParams);
            }catch(PDOException $ex){
                $out[] = $failedInsertQuantity;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

Let's say customer 123 bought 4 of product A and they have 10 locations

```
customerNumber  |  product  |  category  |  startDate  |  expireDate  | stores
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-01      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-01      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-01      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-01      10
```

Because they purchased less than their store count, I insert 4 records. Now if my `$validCheck` query selects all 4 of those records (since they fall in a valid date range) and my loop sees that the array isn't empty, it knows it needs to update those or insert. Let's say they bought 15 this time. Then I would need to insert 6 records, and then update the expiration date of the other 9 records.

```
customerNumber  |  product  |  category  |  startDate  |  expireDate  | stores
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
123                 1           A           2018-08-01    2019-03-11      10
```

There can only ever be a maximum of 10 (store count) records for that customer and product within the valid date range. As soon as the row count for that customer/product reaches the equivalent of stores, it needs to now go through and update equal to the quantity

Update

Currently running this:

```
    $total = $row2['QUANTITY'] + $validCheck;
    if ($total < $row2['STORES']) {
        $insert_count = $row2['QUANTITY'];
        $update_count = 0;
    } else {
        $insert_count = $row2['STORES'] - $validCheck; // insert enough to fill all stores
        $update_count = ($total - $insert_count); // update remainder
    }

    foreach ($i = 0; $i < $insert_count; $i++) {
        try {
            $insertRslt = $insert->execute($insertParams);
        } catch(PDOException $ex){
            $out[] = $failedInsertStore;
        }
    }
    if ($update_count > 0) {
        try {
            $updateParams[':UPDATELIMIT'] = $update_count;
            $updateRslt = $update->execute($updateParams);
        }  catch(PDOException $ex){
            $out[] = $failedInsertStore;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not modifying `$updateParams` or `$insertParams` during the loops. So you're just updating or inserting the same rows over and over.

Comment: Sorry I meant to mention that the params are set outside of a while loop but this takes place inside the while loop

Comment: That doesn't help. They need to change in the `for` loops.

Comment: I guess I'm confused, how exactly would I do that?

Comment: It's hard to tell from what you've written. I guess you should be using `$i` to index into an array that contains information about the record to update or insert.

Comment: Could you give an example of the before/after contents of the table?

Comment: One moment and I can show you an example

Comment: You say that it's not updating the proper records, so it seems like the problem is that the update params are not correct. It will be hard to tell you how to fix that without seeing the actual value of `$updateParams`.

Comment: I updated with the logic and a table example for reference

Comment: I'm totally confused. You start with 4 records, you insert 6. What are the "other 9 records"? And at the end, they all still have the same expiration date as they began with, what did you update?

Comment: No the 2nd example has new expiration dates if you check again. The 'other 9' come from them now buying 15 of the same product. They can only ever have a number of records for that product that equal store count so in that 2nd example it inserts the 6 that now give the 10 row count, but then has to update 9 in order to have the correct number of rows with that expiration date

Comment: You don't need to use UPDATE in a loop, you can just make the WHERE condition select the existing rows that you care about. You can use `LIMIT 9` to restrict it to 9 rows to update.

Comment: All the rows are identical. Why have lots of duplicate rows? Are there other columns that you aren't showing that distinguish them?

Comment: So in the case above, I'm not sure how I would do that. In that case I would insert enough records to equal their stores ( in this case inserting 6 to equal a row count of 10) but then I would still need to update the 9 to reflect the new dates

Comment: The date distinguishes them, It's used to figure out how many products the customer currently has. So if they don't order a certain product for a while it 'expires' . It basically just gives each row it's own date for expiration

Comment: The above example isn't the best at showing that but if those all were to expire and then they ordered 3 later it helps to keep track, in the case that they have multiple stores

Comment: This is running with a bit of other code and I didn't want to confuse the issue but maybe that would help. For the most part this seems to have been working for a while now, but I've run into a case where a count of records for one customer equals 50 or more when they have only 40 stores so I'm thinking that something is off with that logic somewhere

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the logic should be like this:

```
$total = $row2['QUANTITY'] + $validCheck;
if ($total < $row2['STORES']) {
    $insert_count = $row2['QUANTITY'];
    $update_count = 0;
} else {
    $insert_count = $row2['STORES'] - $validCheck; // insert enough to fill all stores
    $update_count = ($total - $insert_count); // update remainder
}
```

Then use `$insert_count` as the repeat count in the `for` loop for inserting new rows. The `UPDATE` query should include `LIMIT :limit`, and then you can bind `$update_count` to the `:limit` placeholder.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $insert_count; $i++) {
    try {
        $insertRslt = $insert->execute($insertParams);
    } catch(PDOException $ex){
        $out[] = $failedInsertStore;
    }
}
if ($update_count > 0) {
    try {
        $updateParams[':limit'] = $update_count;
        $updateRslt = $update->execute($updateParams);
    }  catch(PDOException $ex){
        $out[] = $failedInsertStore;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that makes sense. I'm using PDO but I think I can figure out how to use $update_count in the update query. As for the inserting, you're saying I would use $insert_count in my iterator block? so ```for($i=0; $i<$row2["QUANTITY"]; $i++)``` I would use $insert_count instead of $i?

Comment: I'm just trying to figure out the overall structure of how to incorporate your answer into my existing block

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < $insert_count; $i++)`

Comment: Ah I see, thank you! I'll be trying this and see how it goes

Comment: And all of that should be right before my existing if statement that checks for $validCheck being empty right?

Comment: I don't think you need that check at all. If `$validCheck == 0`, this code will do the right thing.

Comment: Can you check my update above? I'm not able to run that block now

Comment: I got it to run but it's inserting way more than before and doesn't seem to be updating

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how you should rewrite the loops.

Comment: Oh, I see. And that new foreach should go into each section of the if statement? or would it be the if/else by itself and then the loops?

Comment: This is the whole thing, it replaces all your code.

Comment: You have an `if` statement that sets the variables, then two loops after it that use them.

Comment: See, that's what I thought but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. My update to my question above shows what I'm running and it just goes back to the command line without running the code. And I am using the limit parameter in my update query. No errors, it just isn't running

Comment: Wait, shouldn't that be a for loop, not foreach?

Comment: Ok that did get it to run now using the for loop. Still seems to be too many inserts so I'll keep playing with it. Thanks!

Comment: `$validCheck` is the previous number of rows for the customer, right? I think this implements the logic you described. I'm assuming the prepared queries and parameter arrays are correct.

Comment: Try printing out the count variables and see if they match your expectations.

Comment: I think it did logically but I'm checking to see if I missed something in my query and I think I may have